# Extract sentence from text files in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a directory of 18000+ .txt files. Most of the files are emails so are mostly of the format:

```
(Some text)

Subject: Re: Relevant text 

(More text)
```

From each of the .txt files, I need to extract the "Relevant text"

My best result so far has been with

`re.findall(r"(Subject:[^.]*\n\n\n?)",text)`

The output for 3 example files are as follows :

```
['Subject: Re: DMORPH\n\nIn article <>  (Armstrong Jay N) writes:\n>Can someone please tell me where I can ftp DTA or DMORPH?\n\n']

['Subject: Alias phone number wanted\n\n']

['Subject: Re: The 1994 Mustang\n\n']
```

Comment: You want to extract the words after `Subject`?

Comment: Yes, the words after ```Subject:```

Comment: Check my answer, I added a demo link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import re, os
relevant_texts={}
textfilesdir=#enter you text file dir here
for file in os.listdir(textfilesdir):
    if os.path.splitext(file.lower())== '.txt':
        with open(os.path.join(textfilesdir, file) as f:
            subject = re.findall('[sS]{1}ubject:.+\n+', f.read())
            if len(subject):
                relevant_texts[file] = re.sub('[sS]{1}ubject:[ ]*(Re:)*', '', subject[0].strip()).strip()
            else:
                relevant_texts[file] = 'SUBJECT NOT FOUND !!!'
                print('relevant text not found in %s!!!'%file)
```

Comment: This didn't work. It returns *'relevant text not found in {file}!!!'* for all the files..

Comment: Please try the edited code, this time it should be working

Comment: Could you please point out if there is a way I could remove the "Re:" while extracting the subjects? the "Re:" part isn't in all of the texts

Comment: You should try the edited code, It will remove **Re:** whenever it is there in subject

Answer (score 0):

Supposed `texts` are your contents from the files.

```py
import re

texts = [
  'Subject: Re: DMORPH\n\nIn article <> (Armstrong Jay N) writes:\n>Can someone please tell me where I can ftp DTA or DMORPH?',
  'Subject: Alias phone number wanted',
  'Subject: Re: The 1994 Mustang',
]

pattern = re.compile(r'^[sS]ubject:\s(?P<subject>.*)')

for text in texts:
  match = pattern.search(text)
  print(match.group('subject'))
```

Output

```py
Re: DMORPH
Alias phone number wanted
Re: The 1994 Mustang
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/UrWp0C/1

Comment: Will you be able to include all the relevant codes on your question?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.. Really appreciate it.. From what Kuldip Chaudhari pointed out, I was able to solve the problem